# Sorting Nd Numpy Array By Rows In Descending Order

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I want to sort the following matrix by row values:

```
a = array([[1, 4, 6],
           [5, 3, 7],
           [8, 4, 1]])
```

as

```
a = array([[6, 4, 1],
           [7, 5, 3],
           [8, 4, 1]])
```

I'm able to get the sorting indices using `np.argsort(-a)` which returns the following matrix of indices:

```
>>> a_idx = np.argsort(-a)
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

but using these indices to rearrange the original matrix is not happening  for me.

```
>>> a[a_idx]
array([[[8, 4, 1],
        [5, 3, 7],
        [1, 4, 6]],

       [[8, 4, 1],
        [1, 4, 6],
        [5, 3, 7]],

       [[1, 4, 6],
        [5, 3, 7],
        [8, 4, 1]]])
```

How to efficiently accomplish such a task? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, using `.take_along_axis()` method,

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 4, 6],
                  [5, 3, 7],
                  [8, 4, 1]])   
>>> a_idx = np.argsort(-a)
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> np.take_along_axis(a, a_idx, axis=1)        
array([[6, 4, 1],
       [7, 5, 3],
       [8, 4, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 4, 6],
           [5, 3, 7],
           [8, 4, 1]])
print(np.sort(-a,axis=1)*-1)
```